# inheritance in lesscss, doesn't inherit sub classes

Tags: less

this is my `style.less` code:

```css
.transition {
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.shadow {
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #808080;
    -o-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #808080;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #808080;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #808080;
}

    .shadow:hover {
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #a5a5a5;
        -o-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #a5a5a5;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #a5a5a5;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #a5a5a5;
    }


.radius {
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#t1 {
    .shadow;
    .transition;
    .radius;
}
```

but when I hover `#t1` the shadow doesn't change. I want to know why it doesn't work and expect add `#t1:hover` and inherit the style is there any other way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change the `.hover` class to include the `:hover` state as part of the class definition:

```
.hover {
    ...styles...

    &:hover {
        ...hover state styles...
    }
}
.someOtherClass {
    .hover;
}
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/zzzzBov/pen/gaEpr)

Answer (score 2):

In order to have the `:hover` styles generated correctly you need to connect `.shadow` and `.shadow:hover` via the `&` operator so they belong together:

```css
.shadow {
    /*normal styles*/
    &:hover{
       /* hover styles */
    }
}
```

The rest can stay the same, because

```
#t1{
  .shadow;
}
```

will now automatically generate both, the normal and the hover rules.

You can try it out here: [Online-Less-Converter](http://www.marcdonaldson.com/less-2-css-online-converter/)

Every additional block you add to `.shadow` via the `&` operator will automatically be applied to `#t1` as well, so if you add another:

```
.shadow{
    &:hover{}   
    &.foo{
       /* another set of rules*/
    }
}
#t1{
    .shadow; /* this will now generate 3 ruleblocks for #t1*/
}
```

the `.foo` ruleblock will be generated for `#t1` as well:

```
#t1{...}
#t1:hover{...}
#t1.foo{/* another set of rules*/}
```